Door threshold higher on one side
My front door started screeching recently. The sweep is rubbing the threshold. I removed the threshold today and it’s almost a half inch higher on one side. I put all the adjustment screws in the lowest positions also. I’m at the end of my handiness now and my wife is tired of the screeching door. Any ideas?
threshold

You say you lowered the threshold. If you put a piece of paper in there and closed the door, can you pull it out?

TL;DR The Hinges
When a door that used to be straight is now tilted, that usually means a problem with the hinges. Sometimes that can be fixed by just tightening the hinge screws, but that will likely be only a temporary fix.

Remove the hinge pins and take off the door
Unscrew the hinges
Get new screws that are longer than the old screws but have the same size/type heads. If there are varying types of sizes/heads, figure out which is the best match for the hinges. You may even want to take one of the hinges to a hardware store so you can try different screws to see what fits best. That is important because if the heads are larger then the screws won't sit properly in the hinges.
Install the hinges with the new screws.
Hang the door on the hinges.


Excellent. Thanks for replying. I’ll give it a go

Well friendo, it really made it much quieter. I also saw all different types of screw heads in the hinge plates. So I will take your advice and shore it up with longer proper screws. Thanks so much!

Also, if it turns out to still sag after replacing the screws, it's possible the frame has tilted too.  You may be able to straighten the door a little more by shimming the hinges—basically place a layer of some kind of incompressible material beneath the middle and lower hinges before you screw them to the frame (or door).  Something like a thin metal sheet, or even plastic (though it may compress over time).

Why not replace the highest screw of the top hinge with a long one that anchors into the stud behind the frame and see if that changes the sag?
